# Finding Eigenvectors of 3 x 3 matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Yes, I have searched for this question.  I didn't see another question that was asking the same thing, and the answers seemed to gloss over what I'm missing.  I know this is really simple but I can't seem to find where I'm going wrong.

I want to find the eigenvectors of:
$$A = \begin{bmatrix}
1 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & 4 & 5 \\
0 & 0 & 6 \end{bmatrix}$$

Since $A$ is triangular I know the eigenvalues are $1,4,6$.

Using $Av-\lambda I_3 v = 0$,  and factoring out $v$ to get $(A-\lambda I_3)v = 0$,  I get that:

\begin{align}
E_6 = \begin{bmatrix}
-5 & 2 & 3 \\
0 & -2 & 5 \\
0 & 0 & 1 \end{bmatrix}\vec{v} = \vec{0}
\end{align}

Solving for $v_1,v_2,v_3$ I come up with the following equations:

\begin{align*}
-5v_1 + 2v_2 +3v_3 = 0 \\
-2v_2+5v_3 = 0 \\
v_3 = 0
\end{align*}

Clearly $v_3 = 0$, and now we can substitute $v_3$ in the remaining equations. This leads to:
\begin{align*}
-5v_1+2v_2 = 0\\
-2v_2= 0
\end{align*}

But now it's clear that $v_2 = 0$.  This is repeated again for $v_1$ and I've just found that $v_1 = v_2 = v_3 = 0$.  Putting $E_6$ in RREF right away makes this clear at a glance. I know this is wrong because eigenvectors are defined to be not all zeros.

I am interested in where I went wrong, and particularly what theoretical hole in my understanding lead me to this wrong answer.

Comment: ..what is $6-6$?

Comment: @user127.0.0.1 Wow.  Thanks

Comment: You're welcome. Btw: The matrix (that you have called $E_6$ in this special case) has to be singular by construction, no matter what $A$ and corresponding $\lambda$ look like. Thus it was not hard to spot the error :)

Answer (score 1):

$A e_1 = e_1$.

$A(\mu,1,0)^T = (2+\mu, 4 ,0)^T$, hence if we choose $4 \mu = (2+\mu)$, we get $\mu = {2 \over 3}$ and $A({2 \over 3},1,0)^T = 4({2 \over 3}, 1 ,0)^T$.

A similar analysis on $A(x_1,x_2,1)^T = 6 (x_1,x_2,1)^T$ yields $x_1 = {8 \over 5}, x_2 = {5 \over 2}$.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this needs a full answer, but I've decided to add some details to this:

As pointed out in the comments, this is a matter of a simple subtraction mistake ($6-6\ne 1)$, however, you could have stopped and realized you've made a mistake at two points already:

**1) When you found out $v_2$ is zero**: We have a 3x3 matrix and three distinct eigenvalues. Since there has to be at least one eigenvector per eigenvalue (why?), we cannot end up with one having two.

**2) When you found out matrix $E_6$ is regular**: The matrix must be singular by its construction. (Try to prove that!)